# pre build script path and pre build script arguments

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2012

Where can I set pre-build script path and pre-build script arguments for build process template in TFS 2012? I found these options in TFS 2013 as shown in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for for TFS 2012.

1. You will need to add a new activity to your workflow to call a pre-build script or
2. Set your build process to build a MSBuild project file (not a solution). This project file will be your custom build entry point and you can add your pre-build work in this project. Once the pre-build work is done you can start the solution build.